# STM32 неправильно работает логическое выражение

Tags: c, stm32, arm, c99

STM32 контроллер болтается в функции `HAL_Delay()`;

Переопределил функцию с использованием отдельного таймера
Сначала проверка была вида `while (HAL_DELAY_COUNTER){}` переделал на `if HAL_DELAY_COUNTER`. Такой код исправно досчитывает до `0` и продолжает висеть - как будто условие не выполнено.
Оптимизация отключена, `HAL_DELAY_COUNTER` имеет модификатор `volatile`

```
void HAL_Delay(uint32_t Delay)
{
    HAL_DELAY_COUNTER = Delay;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim4);
    HAL_DELAY_TASK:
    if (HAL_DELAY_COUNTER > 0){ goto HAL_DELAY_TASK; }
}
```

Что может быть причиной такого поведения. Контроллер stm32h750, но я это уже где то видел, возможно не смог понять как прошло.
Попробовал сделать условие  if (HAL_DELAY_COUNTER > 1)
считает до 0 и не выходит, то есть условие не срабатывает.

Comment: Укажите метку языка в вопросе

Comment: Что из себя представляет HAL_DELAY_COUNTER? В вашем коде эта переменная никак не меняется. Как вы определяете, что она "считает до 0"?

Comment: volatile uint32_t HAL_DELAY_COUNTER в main где сам метод указанный выше. 

extern uint32_t HAL_DELAY_COUNTER в файле с хэндлами прерываний. 
При заходе в хэндл прерывания по таймеру идет проверка -  
if (HAL_DELAY_COUNTER>0){HAL_DELAY_COUNTER-=1;}
ранее еще было второе условие на else (отключить таймер если дотикало до 0) но потом убрал эту строчку и добавил ее в теле основной функции сразу после проверки на 0. (мол проверили если 0, отключаем таймер, чтобы не генерил прерывания).Убрал потому что думал, что из за этого какие то глюки.